# Gurobi: How can I sum just a part of a variable?

Tags: python, for-loop, matrix, constraints, gurobi

I have the following model:

```
from gurobipy import *

n_units = 1
n_periods = 3
n_ageclasses = 4

units = range(1,n_units+1)
periods = range(1,n_periods+1)
periods_plus1 = periods[:]
periods_plus1.append(max(periods_plus1)+1)
ageclasses = range(1,n_ageclasses+1)
nothickets = ageclasses[1:]


model = Model('MPPM')

HARVEST = model.addVars(units, periods, nothickets, vtype=GRB.INTEGER, name="HARVEST")
FOREST = model.addVars(units, periods_plus1, ageclasses, vtype=GRB.INTEGER, name="FOREST")


model.addConstrs((quicksum(HARVEST[(k+1), (t+1), nothicket] for k in range(n_units) for t in range(n_periods) for nothicket in nothickets)  == FOREST[unit, period+1, 1] for unit in units for period in periods if period < max(periods_plus1)), name="A_Thicket")
```

I have a problem with formulating the constraint. I want for every unit and every period to sum the nothickets part of the variable HARVEST. Concretely I want x<sub>k=1,t=1,2</sub> + x<sub>k=1,t=1,3</sub> + x<sub>k=1,t=1,4</sub> 
and so on. This should result in only three ones per row of the constraint matrix. But with the formulation above I get 9 ones.
I tried to use a for loop outside of the sum, but this results in another problem:

```
 for k in range(n_units):
    for t in range(n_periods):
        model.addConstrs((quicksum(HARVEST[(k+1), (t+1), nothicket] for nothicket in nothickets)  == FOREST[unit,period+1, 1] for unit in units for period in periods if period < max(periods_plus1)), name="A_Thicket")
```

With this formulation I get this matrix:
[constraint matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3dVy.jpg)

But what I want is:

```
row_idx | col_idx | coeff
0   | 0  | 1
0   | 1  | 1
0   | 2  | 1
0   | 13  | -1
1   | 3  | 1
1   | 4  | 1
1   | 5  | 1
1   | 17  | -1
2   | 6  | 1
2   | 7  | 1
2   | 8  | 1
2   | 21  | -1
```

Can anybody please help me to reformulate this constraint?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
 model.addConstrs((HARVEST.sum(unit, period, '*') == ...
```